# OpenCV Remap with maps of shape map1 (h,w,2) and shape map2 (h,w)

Tags: opencv, image-processing, computer-vision, opencv3.0, camera-calibration

What does `cv2.remap(img, map1, map2, interpolation=cv2.INTER_LINEAR)` do when the `map1` has a shape `(h,w,2)` and `map2` a shape `(h,w)`.
These maps come as an output to the `cv2.fisheye.initUndistortRectifyMap` but the documentation is not very clear. If I change the `map2` variable for a `numpy.array([],dtype=np.int16)` it will still give me a output that looks close to the one without omitting `map2` but there are differences.

Does `cv2.remap` change the data type of `img` during this process?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, the documentation is unfortunately not quite clear on this.  However, if you take a look at [`cv2.remap`](https://docs.opencv.org/3.4/da/d54/group__imgproc__transform.html#gab75ef31ce5cdfb5c44b6da5f3b908ea4) and
[`cv2.computeMaps`](https://docs.opencv.org/3.4/da/d54/group__imgproc__transform.html#ga9156732fa8f01be9ebd1a194f2728b7f)  this tells you what they actually mean.

In summary, the output of `cv2.fisheye.initUndistortRectifyMap` provides two maps where the first map is a two channel matrix where the first channel are the `x` coordinates and the second channel are the `y` coordinates for the remapping.  Now what is different is that this is a result of **fixed-point** precision instead of a typical floating-point precision matrix.  Fixed-point is primarily used for computational speedups in calculating the remapped image.  The second map is a table of interpolation coefficients so that when you use this in concert with the first map, it provides nearly identical results compared to using the normal floating-point precision matrices but with great computational savings.

By omitting the second map, you are still getting decent results, but the second map being empty produces a loss of precision as you are not providing the interpolation table to produce what would have been created if you used a floating-point precision map. This is why you are viewing an image with somewhat lower quality.

Comment: Ok. Well I finally understand now. Thank you very much. 

The reason to all of this is to increase the speed of the remap. What I want to do is to crop the image and crop the maps, then remap a smaller portion of the image. But here in the map1 I then need to substract the x amount of pixels cropped left and the y amount of pixels cropped from the top. I am not sure if there is any substraction to do on map2 part of image. 

Now I see that one way would also be to convert the maps to (CV_32FC1, CV_32FC1) substract cropping values left and top and then convert back to (CV_16SC2, CV_16UC1).

Comment: Would it be possible to just substract the crop values from (CV_16SC2) and leave CV_16UC1 unchanged. I guess CV_16UC1 would be wrong then.

Comment: @Sadikov Using `cv2.computeMaps` then performing the crop on this intermediate result and converting back is the safest approach IMHO.  As you mentioned, if you performed the subtraction then the interpolation table provided as `map2` no longer is correct.

Comment: I think that is what I am going to do then. Thanks. Also, do you happen to know whether the `remap` changes the image data type internally at some point?

Comment: @Sadikov Yes and no.  They don't change the image type, but they operate on a per-pixel basis meaning that the actual pixel values themselves get casted to a floating-point precision type individually, then the calculations are computed and then are converted back to an integer type.  So the actual input image itself is never transformed, but the interpolation calculates do temporarily promote the pixel values in separate variables prior to the remapping.  I'm not sure if this answered your question but I hope it did!